# How to launch an application on VMware Horizon and obtain a web link to its session using PowerCLI?

Tags: powershell, vmware, powercli

I am a Linux user seeking guidance on automating the process of launching VMware Horizon applications and obtaining session web links using PowerCLI.

> Please note that I have already posted a feature request regarding this functionality on the PowerCLI Example Scripts GitHub page asking some questions, but I wanted to reach out to the broader Stack Overflow community for additional insights.

##### What I have tried:

- I have explored the REST API of VMware Horizon without success in finding an appropriate endpoint for launching applications and retrieving session web links.
- have investigated the `vmware-view` utility, but it does not fulfill my requirements.

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this task using PowerCLI or any of its helper libraries. Specifically, I aim to:

- Automate the launching of VMware Horizon applications through PowerCLI.
- Programmatically obtain session web links to access the launched applications in any browser.

If there are existing PowerCLI cmdlets, functions, or scripts that can help accomplish these objectives, I would be grateful for guidance on how to utilize them effectively. Any sample scripts or step-by-step instructions would be highly appreciated.

I am open to alternative approaches or workarounds that can enable the automated launch of VMware Horizon applications and the retrieval of session web links.

I look forward to any suggestions or recommendations that can help me achieve my goal.

Comment: You're probably better off asking this in the VMware forums - https://communities.vmware.com/